# How get data array from JSON object in python?

Tags: python, jquery, json, django

I have a jquery POST function like this :

```
 $.post(data_send_url,
    {
        all_letters:["A","B","C"]
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert(data);
});
```

In the server side when I access it using `request.data` in a `Django view function` I get 
`<QueryDict: {'all_letters[]': ['e', 'r', 'p']}>`. How can I get a Python list like `all_letters = ['e','r','p']` ?

Comment: Did you tried `request.data[all_letters]` ? Or `json.loads` ?

Comment: `request.data["all_letters"]` gives `key error`,`request.data.get("all_letters")` gives `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'QueryDict'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try to `stringify` the `array`  and after this use `json.loads` ?

```
$.post(data_send_url,
    {
        all_letters: JSON.stringify(["A","B","C"])
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert(data);
});

# and after this use json.loads
import json

print(json.loads(request.data['all_letters']))
```

Comment: try to `print(request.POST)` what you get ? show me

Comment: `<QueryDict: {'all_letters[]': ['a', 'b', 'c']}>`

Comment: @TaohidulIslam i make and update try something like this

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to follow your previous suggestion and it leads me to the solution.

Comment: You are welcome :) if it is posible can you accepted the answer :) ?

Comment: Okay, and will you check my answer please?

Comment: maybe `django` convert it automatically ?

Comment: `request.data.get("all_letters")` gives `["A","B","C"]` and json.loads(request.data.get("all_letters")) gives `['A','B','C']` !

Answer (score 2):

This code solved my problem:

```
$.post(data_send_url,
    {
        all_letters:JSON.stringify(["A","B","C"]), //JSON.stringify added
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert(data);
});
```

And in views.py

```
json.loads(request.data.get("all_letters"))
json.loads(request.POST["all_letters"]) #both of these work fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'all_letter[]' as key just like below:

```
request.data["all_letters[]"]
```

This might work otherwise try to construct querydict properly in JS code and try to access it.

Comment: It shows `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'all_letters` '